# Rethrowing exception not being caught

Tags: c#

I have an extension method that runs a Task in the background and I put it in a try-catch block to handle any exception that it throws. The problem is that visual studio always stops on the rethrow portion of my code and I am not sure why.

```
try {
    task.RunInBackground();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do something
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are not awaiting your task.RunInBackground statement, so your try catch has no effect

Comment: that's what throw is for

Comment: You say it's not being caught, but you don't say what part of your code you expect to catch it, and I don't see any reason why you might think any part of your code would catch it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you say Visual Studio always stops, do you just mean that it does not work properly when you debug only? Then it stops because it's an uncaught exception, and you need to change your setting with regards to that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to await the task like this:

```
try {
    await task.RunInBackground();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do something
}
```

Avoid as much as possible using async void. Remove the `async void` by replacing it with `async Task` like below :

```
public static async Task RunInBackground(this Task task) {
    // ....
}
```

If you need to know why to avoid async void check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) from msdn.

Comment: I wanted to just fire and forget the task, so that's why I used async void. If I just await it, I will never execute anything beyond the await call. My task runs in an infinite while loop.

Comment: I f you need to fire an dforget then what did you throw the exception into the Task? just ignore the exception then (which is not a good idea)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
task.RunInBackground().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    throw t.Exception;
},
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This code will not stop for the task, until an exception was thrown by that task.